# Использовать имя одной переменной для создания второй

Tags: php

Возникла надобность использовать имя одной переменной для создания второй.

Вот мой нерабочий вариант:

```
 <?php
 $name = "name";
 $name.$var = 10;
 echo $namevar;     
  ?>
```

Comment: Создание таких переменных - это то, за что Сатана назовёт Вас плохим. Не делайте так даже в кошмарах.

Comment: То есть решение вы не знаете?

Comment: `$name = 'var'; $$name = 1234; var_dump ($var);` извращайтесь наздоровье

Comment: Для супер упоротых можно ещё конструкцию использовать `${$name . 'name'} `

Comment: Ещё есть конструкция `extract`, за которую Страуструп проклял PHP до седьмого колена. Демон, прекращайте учить детей плохому!

Answer (score 2):

К примеру так:

```
<?php
 $name = "name";
 $new_name = $name . 'var';
 $$new_name = 10;
 echo $namevar;     
  ?>
```